# "No operating system found" after clean install of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, bios

On a Lenovo ThinkCentre desktop, after doing a clean install of Ubuntu I get the error "no operating system found".

This is the first thing I see when booting the computer, there is nothing printed before.

I installed Ubuntu as "erase disk and install Ubuntu". There is no other OS on the disk.

[image]

Boot mode in BIOS is set to UEFI. I've set this mode before booting from USB and installing the system.

[image]

Hardware:

- Lenovo ThinkCentre M92p
- only one HDD - WDC WDS240G2G0A (240GB SSD), which was working fine with Windows just before installing Ubuntu
- Intel i5-3470T, 8GB RAM

What am I missing?

More details about the partitioning that was created:

[image: Ubuntu Disks app]

fdisk:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 223.58 GiB, 240065183744 bytes, 468877312 sectors
Disk model: WDC WDS240G2G0A-
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D018D616-4492-4595-8654-4C4C81B0DBB5

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 468875263 467824640 223.1G Linux filesystem
```

gdisk:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 468877312 sectors, 223.6 GiB
Model: WDC WDS240G2G0A-
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): D018D616-4492-4595-8654-4C4C81B0DBB5
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 468877278
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4029 sectors (2.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2         1050624       468875263   223.1 GiB   8300
```

Comment: Do you have more than one disk in your system? Lets stick with UEFI --  what partitions get made on your target hdd (an EFI, a root, home, swap, etc.)?  Any errors produced on the install? A second disk will not get the bootloaders you might expect (bug).

Comment: And - again sticking with UEFI - after installing please check UEFI > Boot and make sure the correct boot order is selected.

Comment: There's only one HDD that worked with Windows before. I've added the output of fdisk and gdisk. No errors during the install.

Comment: 1. I have a Lenovo Thinkstation C30, maybe similar to your Thinkcentre, and I have no problems installing and booting into it. Please tell us more details, for example the model number and the graphics chip/card. Knowing more about your computer will help us help you; 2. When you write "Ununtu 22.04 boots from USB, but not from cleanly formatted HDD", what do you mean by "not by ..."? Is there any option to boot the internal drive at all? Does it try booting and print some error output? In other words, how far does the boot process continue until it fails?

Comment: Is your drive in AHCI mode ? Ubuntu supports I think only AHCI or you have to have special drivers for your hardware

Comment: @ubfan1 I've changed boot mode to UEFI-only in BIOS, reinstalled and posted the output of fdisk and gdisk, anything else I can add?

Comment: @ChanganAuto done - reinstalled with UEFI only, the boot order looks OK to me but here's a picture to verify: https://imgur.com/E7bxqWw

Comment: @UnderTheHoud yes, the drive is in AHCI mode, here's how I checked it: https://imgur.com/8JUkkzl

Comment: @sudodus 
1) I added the hardware details to the question, it's Lenovo ThinkCentre M92p with Intel i5-3470T, 8GB RAM. The HDD (only one) is WDC WDS240G2G0A (240GB SSD). Anything else may be relevant?
2) I added a picture of the error message. It shows up as the first thing I see on the screen, before any other message. It looks like something related to BIOS, before Ubuntu starts loading.

Comment: @ssobczak, Thanks for the details. This computer *should* work well with the 22.04 LTS version of Ubuntu. 1. I get a temporary boot menu when I tap F12 repeatedly directly after {power on | reboot}. Please try that and check which devices are shown as bootable devices (and select the internal drive if possible); 2. You could try by extracting a [compressed Ubuntu amd64 image file to the internal drive](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current). It can boot both from UEFI mode and BIOS mode (alias legacy mode); try booting in both modes.

Comment: [This link to the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692) shows what kind of alternate installation, that I suggest. If you post in that thread, you might get help from some more people, so the chance to succeed will increase.

Comment: Try going into the BIOS, go to the startup tab, and change "Boot Mode" to "Legacy" CSM must be enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for all your help, this was very interesting. My machine had an old BIOS, which did NOT expose an option to disable "Compatibility support Module".

Only after updating BIOS the option showed up (as Enabled by default). When I disabled it, Ubuntu boots fine.

So if someone comes here with the similar problem - if you don't see this option in BIOS, try to update it first.

[image]

Comment: +1+1; Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Comment: THANK YOU!! You are my hero! I spent the morning trying all kinds of other troubleshooting and settings changes to no avail. Can't believe it this simple change did it

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with a lenovo thinkcentre. Tried moving HDD up the boot list. tried resizing and formatting some of my previous partitions. Ultimately ended up in a "no operating system found" loop. Was not able to even F1 into bios anymore. As a work-around, I opted for the "OEM install (for manufacturers)" from a bootable usb of 22.10. That seemed to repair the boot mode.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to boot by going into the BIOS, go to the startup tab, and change "Boot Mode" to "Legacy"

CSM must be enabled.